# Why does this Integral question need to be in radians?

Tags: integration

I was doing this integral question and when I submitted the limits in it was incorrect. I submitted in the converted limits in degrees but they wanted radians. Why is that? If the question asks me for an EXACT value should I always calculate my limits in radians?
[image]

Comment: Because $\cos(90)$ is not $0$.

Comment: I've added to my answer, so I've done an integral (a slightly simpler one than this) both in radians and in degrees below, coming up with the same answer both ways, but you see that the method using radians is simpler. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac d {dx}\sin x = \Big(\text{constant}\cdot\cos x\Big).
$$

If $x$ is in radians, then the "constant" is $1$; otherwise it is not.

You could do the whole problem in degrees, but you'd need to take that constant into account at every step.

Let's try a simpler problem first in radians and then in degrees:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\sqrt 2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} = {} & \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{2\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{4 - 4\sin^2\theta}}  \\
& \text{where }x=2\sin\theta,\  dx=2\cos\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta = \frac \pi 4.
\end{align}
Now in degrees:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\sqrt2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} = {} & \int_{0^\circ}^{45^\circ} \frac{\frac{2\pi}{180}\cos(\theta^\circ)\,d\theta^\circ}{\sqrt{4-4\sin^2(\theta^\circ)}} \\
& \text{where }x=2\sin(\theta^\circ),\  dx= \frac{2\pi}{180}\cos(\theta^\circ)\,d\theta^\circ \\[12pt]
= {} & \int_{0^\circ}^{45^\circ} \frac{\pi}{180}\,d\theta^\circ = \frac \pi {180}\cdot 45 = \frac \pi 4.
\end{align}